# ssh key generation using dockerfile

Tags: docker, ssh-keys, dockerfile

I am using Docker for few of my projects, where one requirement is to generate ssh keys using Docker file, so that when the container builds it will generate a pair of rsa keys.I have seen some examples where key generation happens via .sh file and Dockerfile has the commond to run that .sh file. Is there a way we can do it directly in Dockerfile instead of .sh

Currently I am using following in Dockerfile to generate ssh key pair. But this gives me error saying "/bin/sh ssh-keygen not found"

```
RUN ssh-keygen -q -t rsa -N '' -f /home/docker/.ssh/id_rsa
```

will be really very helpful if someone can provide a way to achieve the same.

Thanks,
Yash

Comment: Why do you need ssh ??

Comment: Hi , I have a web app which uses ssh key authentication from host machine to perform any action , thats why.

Comment: the name of the key generation tool is a bit misleading. It is part of open SSH, that's why.

Answer (score 58):

The problem is that ssh-keygen is not available in your container yet. This can be easily solved, for example by installing the openssl-client package on a ubuntu base image.

The following Dockerfile does precisely that and places a key in the container's root folder

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

RUN apt-get -y install openssh-client
RUN ssh-keygen -q -t rsa -N '' -f /id_rsa
```

**BUT READ THIS:**
My strong advice is not to place keys, certificates whatsoever into the container's file system at all! This might lead to strong security risks, as essentially anyone who obtains the container image can authenticate himself at services the key is valid for; it forces you to handle container images with the same care you would treat cryptographic keys and certificates!

Hence, it is advisable to keep the keys outside of the container. This can be easily achieved by using Docker VOLUMES; and you'd simply mount a volume holding keys/containers into the Docker container when launching it.

**CREATING KEYS OUTSIDE THE CONTAINER**
The following Dockerfile does instead create the key once the container is started, and it may be used to create the key outside the container's file system

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
RUN apt-get -y install openssh-client 
CMD ssh-keygen -q -t rsa -N '' -f /keys/id_rsa
```

First, build the container with the following command:

```
docker build -t keygen-container .
```

Starting the container using

```
docker run -v /tmp/:/keys keygen-container
```

will create a key on the host in /tmp.

Comment: Hi eliasw, Thanks a lot :) is there a way I can generate it outside container like in /home dir of docker? I was also trying to echo something in /etc/hosts/ file from Dockerfile, but no success :( , do you have any idea how this can be achieved?

Comment: Actually, this is pretty straightforward:

1) On your host machine, run ssh-keygen to create your keys. For example, in /home/docker
2) Use -v to mount /home/docker into the container. See the [Docker Documentation] (https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/#volume-def) on Volumes for a precise description.

Comment: ok, got it , but what I want is to generate ssh keys outside container in my host machine via Dockerfile. Seems its impossible, will have to do it manually by running ssh-keygen.

Comment: no, a Dockerfile may also create keys outside the container. I've added a second Dockerfile above that does the trick.

Comment: Hi, thankyou so much . it does the trick exactly the way i wanted :) thanks a lot !!

Comment: How do you stop it from asking you to overwrite the file (after it has been generated the first time, when running the container, it prompts for Overwrite)?
/keys/id_rsa already exists.
Overwrite (y/n)?

Comment: RUN apt-get update before apt install openssh its needed.

Answer (score 6):

The answer is almost correct above but you need to apt-get update first. Maybe it was correct on the previous ubuntu image but did not work for me. Also, I remove any id_rsa files that could exist on localhost directory first.

```
printf "FROM ubuntu:latest \nRUN apt-get update; apt-get -y install openssh-client \nCMD rm /keys/id_rsa*; ssh-keygen -q -t rsa -N '' -f /keys/id_rsa" > Dockerfile
docker build -t keygen-container .
docker run -v /tmp/:/keys keygen-container
```