# How to use .env variable in Dockerfile in command?

Tags: docker

I have variable in .env `EMAIL=mail@mail.com`
My docker-compose.yml look:

```
services:
  web:
    container_name: ${NAME}}
    environment:
      EMAIL: ${EMAIL}
    build: "."
    ports:
      - 3011:3000
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - "./app:/src/app"
```

I want use EMAIL var in dockerfile, in command:

```
RUN  ssh-keygen -q -t rsa -N "EMAIL"  -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

How look like this command? "${EMAIL}"?

Comment: You probably shouldn't `RUN ssh-keygen` in a Dockerfile at all: the private key can be almost trivially extracted, and the key material will change every time you rebuild the image.  See the addendum to the [longer answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27504514) to [ssh key generation using dockerfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27504187/ssh-key-generation-using-dockerfile) for a better approach, which would honor the `environment:` setting.

Answer (score 1):

For this you should use [build args](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/build/#args):

```yaml
# docker-compose.yml
services:
  web:
    build:
      context: "."
      args:
        EMAIL: ${EMAIL}
   # ...
```

```dockerfile
# Dockerfile

# ...

ARG EMAIL
RUN ssh-keygen -q -t rsa -N "${EMAIL}" -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Comment: thanks! But why ARG not ENV? What is diffrent?

Comment: @arcan second question:
- I have problem beacouse 
RUN ssh-keygen  -b 2048 -t rsa -N "${EMAIL}"  -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa 
- added email to ssh like: ... kBl7CewuGO1ZQjN6KGa5 root@buildkitsandbox not my mail.
- this command add passphrase, how I can remove it?